# Saving a SHAP Text Plot in Word Level

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, huggingface-transformers, shap

My current shap text plot with invoking

```
shap.plots.text
```

works for token-based shap values. Is there a way to concatenate all the subwords into words and save it as a .png file with dpi=300?

I have tried

```
shap.plots.text(shap_values[idx])
plt.savefig(img_path, dpi=300)
```

but the resulting image was blank.

Comment: Please [reprex]